Sanity internationalization with sanity-plugin-internationalized-array
I'm using sanity as a CMS for my project with  sanity-plugin-internationalized-array for the internationalization feature .
This is my config :
// sanity.config.ts

export default defineConfig({
    name: 'default',
    title: 'project',

    projectId: 'project_id',
    dataset: 'production',
    plugins: [
        internationalizedArray({
      languages: [
        {id: 'en', title: 'English'},
        {id: 'fr', title: 'French'}
      ],
      defaultLanguages: ['en'],
      fieldTypes: ['string'],
    }),     
})

// document/project.js

export default defineType({
    name: 'project.category',
    title: 'Project category',
    type: 'document',
    icon: GoProject,
    fields: [
        defineField({
            name: 'name',
            type: 'string',
        }),
        defineField({
            name: 'title',
            type: 'internationalizedArrayString',
        }),
        defineField({
            name: 'body',
            type: 'array',
            of: [
                { type: 'block' },
                imageBlock,
                defineArrayMember({
                    type: 'code',
                    options: {
                        withFilename: true,
                    },
                }),
            ],
        }),
    ],
})

How to make type: 'block' input accept the internationalizedArrayString type ?
